# How to print count in view using Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to Codeigniter and I am facing an issue with printing count in admin dashboard.

The following code is what I am trying now. Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

**my model**

```
function todayorder(){
    $sql=$this->db->query("select count(*) as count from orders where order_date_time >= CURDATE()");
    return  $sql->row();
}
```

**controller**

```
public function orderlist(){
    if(isset($_SESSION['admin_id'])){

        $data["row"]=$this->picShuModel->orderlist();
        $this->load->view('admin/index',$data);

        $query = $this->picShuModel->todayorder();
        $data['count'] = $query->count;

        $this->load->view('admin/index',$data);



    }else{
        $this->load->view('admin/login'); 
    }

}
```

**and my view*** in the dashboard

```
<?php foreach($data as $count){echo $count;}?>
```

Comment: Try `<?=$count;?>` on your `admin/index` view page. No need of loop

Comment: $sql->row(); will return only one row  use $sql->result(); instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your view you can directly use $count as a variable.

Change

```
<?php foreach($data as $count){echo $count;}?>
```

To

```
echo $count;
```

### Update

```
public function orderlist(){
    if(isset($_SESSION['admin_id'])){

        $data["row"]=$this->picShuModel->orderlist();

        $query = $this->picShuModel->todayorder();
        $data['count'] = $query->count;

        $this->load->view('admin/index',$data);



    }else{
        $this->load->view('admin/login'); 
    }

}
```

Comment: @samit i tried  I'm getting following error :-     Undefined variable: count

Comment: remove the first line `$this->load->view('admin/index',$data);` you have 2 lines

Comment: Thanks to @RyukLee I missed that. I have updated my answer. Please check now.

Answer (score 2):

This below line assigns count to array variable

```
$data['count'] = $query->count;
```

To access count in view page

```
<?php 
    echo $count ; // you have use element of data rather $data. this print the count value 
?>
```

In controller you are loading view page twice, load view page once